# How to fix strange xticks intervals for datetime.time type in pandas plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I have the following kind of dataframe:

[image]

The plot of xticks is very strange. How to fix it? I think '15:00, 16:00,...' is natural x-ticks.

[image]

#### Update

This is code generate above plot.

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import numpy as np
d = pd.DataFrame([np.random.rand(3) for _ in range(9)])
d.index = [datetime.time(i, 0) for i in range(15,24)]
d.plot()
```

Comment: Please provide some runnable code so that we are able to provide a better answer to your specific problem

Answer (score 0):

This is weird because in the doc:

```
use_index : boolean, default True
    Use index as ticks for x axis
```

Setting this manually to `True`, does not change anything.

However you can do this as a workaround:

```
d.plot(xticks=d.index)
```

[image: pandas line plot date]

My default matplotlib parameters are different, so that's why it looks different, but it is what you want.

HTH